# .DWG and .DGN will not drop in to ArcMap 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-formats, cad

I am attempting to bring in Microstation data (.DGN) into a working ArcMap file. Every time I attempt to drop the data in the map I get the following error message... (Error could not open the specified file)

The original files were .DGN, I had a friend convert them to .DWG and have received the same error. I have also attempted to use the {CAD to Geodatabase} tool on both file extension types and, once again, get the same error message when I try to add the data to the map.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you have to use the add data button.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Adding_CAD_data_to_ArcMap